# How to prevent table row from changing its height when overlap some elements in it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table in my opened modal dialog. I need that dropdownlist overlap over the modal dialog. This dropdownlist is placed inside of td with class "clients". But when I apply a style "position: relative; z-index: 100;" the tr becomes higher- the height of tr becames the same as the height of div class="chosen-drop".

```
<td class="clients">
      <select class="chzn-select" id="ClientIds" multiple="multiple" name="ClientIds" style="display: none;">
          <option value="0">All</option>
          <option value="12">Client 1</option>
          <option value="22">Client 2</option>
      </select>
      <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" title="">
          <ul class="chosen-choices">
             <li class="search-field">
                  <input type="text" value="Choose client" class="default" autocomplete="off">
             </li>
          </ul>

          @*here I add a style to overlap@
          <div class="chosen-drop" style="position: relative; z-index: 100;">
              <ul class="chosen-results">
                  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0">All</li>
                  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">Client 1</li>
                  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">Client 2</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
 </td>
```

The dropdown overlaps modal dialog but it changes the table row height.

What can I do to prevent tr from changing its height?

Comment: Working fiddle please?

Comment: Use css to set the desired height: `tr { height: #px }`